# flash as3 xml cdata bold tags rendered in htmlText with an embedded font

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, fonts, cdata, htmltext

I'm just trying to get flash to render bold text in a dynamic text field with an embedded font, using data I've imported from an xml file using CDATA. Anyone know how to do this?

XML File:

```
<description><![CDATA[ FOR THE PAST TWO YEARS, <b>SUPERFAD</b> HAS WORKED CLOSELY WITH THE <b>MARTIN AGENCY</b> TO VISUALIZE THE ORIGINAL WORKS OF <b>SPORT CAMPAIGN</b>. THE CAMPAIGN SPOTLIGHTS THE EXTREME ATHLETES OF THE VARIOUS EVENTS AS ARTISTS IN THEIR OWN WORLD, USING THE TOOLS OF THEIR SPORT TO CREATE LASTING WORKS OF ART]]></description>
```

and as3 code:

```
project_desc = myXML.projects.project[cp].description.toUpperCase();
container.header.t_desc.htmlText = project_desc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the text you want to be bold in **span** tags with a class name.

```
<description><![CDATA[ FOR THE PAST TWO YEARS, <span class="myBoldText">SUPERFAD</span> HAS WORKED...</description>
```

Then use a **StyleSheet** object to style it within your actionScript.

```
var my_styleSheet = new StyleSheet();
var n:Object = new Object();
n.fontWeight = 'bold';
my_styleSheet.setStyle('.myBoldText', n);
container.header.t_desc.styleSheet = my_styleSheet;
container.header.t_desc.htmlText = project_desc;
```

Don't forget to import the styleSheet class!

```
import flash.text.StyleSheet;
```

More info on the StyleSheet class here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/StyleSheet.html

Comment: Hey guys - this worked great - I actually ended up using an external stylesheet, and this article here was super useful: http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/design/master-html-formatted-text-in-flash/